# ionic firebase - TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at Firebase.getToken

Tags: angular, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework

I am following a little tutorial to install and use firebase,

But I can't even pass the part where I have to do

`this.firebase.getToken().then(token => {...},error => {...});`

because I have this error :

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>       at Firebase.getToken

the module is imported like this :

```
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase/ngx';
```

note that if I dont put `/ngx` at the end of the import, I get an provider error ...

I tried to install this :
`npm i rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 promise-polyfill --save`

but nothing changed

`ionic info` :

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.9.0 (/.../.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.2/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 21 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 25.1.7 (/.../Library/Android/SDK)
   ios-deploy        : 1.9.4
   ios-sim           : 5.0.13
   NodeJS            : v9.11.2 (/.../.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.2/bin/node)
   npm               : 5.6.0
   OS                : macOS Mojave
   Xcode             : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

any idea ? I quite lost here

EDIT :

`package.json` :

```
    "angularfire2": "^5.1.1",
    "firebase": "^5.8.1",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^5.0.0",
```

Comment: We have no way of knowing what `this.firebase` is in `this.firebase.getToken()`. But note that the method is called `getIdToken()` in recent SDK versions. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getIdToken

Comment: Downgrade your firebase plugin and add this version of firebase 4.18.0

Answer (score 12):

I have answered a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54398403/6617276

Check your project type in ionic.config.json file.

If the type is **"ionic-angular"**, then install 4.x.x version.

```
npm i -s @ionic-native/firebase@4.20.0
```

If the type is **"angular"**, then install 5.x.x-beta version

```
npm i -s @ionic-native/firebase@5.0.0-beta.24
```

**Note**:

Add ngx at the end of import only if you are using **Angular 6**

```
import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase/ngx';
```

if not remove **ngx** from the import both in app.module.ts and app.component.ts

```
import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase';
```

Refencence:https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15225#issuecomment-414074074

Comment: Now I want to cry :'( so much time wasted on an impossible to debug, impossible to guess problem ! Thank you @Rathnakara S !