# ionic 3 native plugins stopped working . I tried putting ngx at last.the red line error is gone.But the plugin is not working

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

```
import { Market } from '@ionic-native/market/ngx';

    constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen,
        private market: Market
        ) {
        this.initializeApp();
        this.market.open('io.ionic.expensemanager2018');
      }

    this.market.open('io.ionic.expensemanager2018');
```

and the error I'm getting is:

```
DetailsPage.html:95 ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Market.open (index.js:27)
    at DetailsPage.webpackJsonp.52.DetailsPage.faq (details.ts:29)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (DetailsPage.html:95)
    at handleEvent (core.js:13589)
    at callWithDebugCon(core.js:15098)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14685)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:10004)
    at core.js:10629
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:2628)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
```

I've have tried also degrading the version but nothing seems to be working. Please help.

Comment: Please try and find a title that usefully sums up your question - how does `plugin is not working` manifest? What worked before? (What is that `red line error`?)

Answer (score 4):

Check your project type in ionic.config.json file.

If the type is **"ionic-angular"**, then install 4.x.x version.

In your case

```
npm i -s @ionic-native/market@4.20.0
```

If the type is **"angular"**, then install 5.x.x-beta version

```
npm i -s @ionic-native/market@5.0.0-beta.24
```

**Note**:

Add ngx at the end of import only if you are using **Angular 6**

```
import { Market } from '@ionic-native/market/ngx';
```

if not remove ngx from the import both in app.module.ts and app.component.ts

```
import { Market } from '@ionic-native/market';
```

Refencence:https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15225#issuecomment-414074074