# IONIC 3: Plugin BackgroundMode dont work: Object(…) is not a function

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to run the code “this.backgroundMode.enable()” in my project, but it shows me the following error:

> "Object(...) is not a function"

It imports it in app.module.ts in the following way:

```
import {BackgroundMode} from '@ ionic-native / background-mode / ngx';
...
providers: [
...
BackgroundMode
...]
```

And in the page (in my case is in app.component.ts, after deviceready, like the official documentation says) i use like:

```
import {BackgroundMode} from '@ ionic-native / background-mode / ngx';
constructor(private backgroundMode: BackgroundMode) { }
...
this.backgroundMode.enable();
```

Please I need to **run this plugin** in my project

Comment: can u try in app.module.ts import plugin without /ngx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have answered a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54398403/6617276

Check your project type in ionic.config.json file.

If the type is **"ionic-angular"**, then install 4.x.x version.

```
npm i -s @ionic-native/background-mode@4.20.0
```

If the type is **"angular"**, then install 5.x.x-beta version

```
npm i -s @ionic-native/background-mode@5.0.0-beta.24
```

**Note**:

Add ngx at the end of import only if you are using **Angular 6**

```
import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode/ngx';
```

if not remove **ngx** from the import both in app.module.ts and app.component.ts

```
import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode';
```

Comment: Perfect, now works the plugin!  But now it returns me "Undefined" for "this.backgroundMode.enable()".... can you help me?

Comment: this.backgroundMode.enable() is a void method it won't return anything, it only enables the backgroundMode. To check if background mode is enabled or not  you can use this.backgroundMode.isEnabled() which returns a boolean value. To check if the background mode is active you can use this.backgroundMode.isActive()

Comment: Okay its fine.... but, how can I test when this.backgroundMode.isActive() is true? 
I need that at the moment the app is in backgroundMode (whatever the moment), the app will detect that it is in backgroundMode

Comment: When an app becomes inactive (runs in the background) Cordova fires the "pause" event, you can subscribe to that event and check whether backgroundMode.isActive() . Something like , platform.pause.subsribe(()=>{  if(this.backgroundMode.isActive()){ console.log("Background mode is active") }  }) . Forgive me, it's difficult to write the code in the comment section

Comment: thank you: the background-mode@4.20.0 (4.20 version) was the trick (and not 5.x)