# Object(...) is not a function When Using Android Permissions Plugin Ionic 3 Angular 5

Tags: ionic3, angular5, android-permissions

I have Setup IONIC 3 and ANGULAR 5.2.x And i want to add some download / upload files functionality so i installed android-permissions plugin of cordova and include in app.module.ts and app.component.ts as per the ionic documentation
but when i add code for checkpermission and request permission like below

```js
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions/ngx';

constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    public menu: MenuController,
    public statusBar: StatusBar,
    public splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    public androidPermissions:AndroidPermissions
  ) {
  
  this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA).then(
      result => console.log('Has permission?',result.hasPermission),
      err => this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA)
    );

    this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions([this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA, this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.GET_ACCOUNTS]);
    
  }
```

throw an error like below image

[object(...) is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJxGL.png)

Comment: cordova plugins dont work with ionic serve.. only in a device/emulator and seems to me you need to test this particular one in an android device

Comment: Yes i tried on device it gives same error but on machine at least it have to execute the script and throw proper error that is cordova not available or something like that.
and the strange thing is i tried with new blank setup of IONIC 3 and Angular 5 i face same error without any extra code or any cordova plugins

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54398504/4826457) help?

Comment: Yes little bit, issue resolved by version changing reinstalled 4.20.0 version of android permissions Thanks @suraj rao