# Issue when importing FileTransfer - ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I have installed filetransfer plugin as it mention [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/)

Here is the code in the app.module.ts:

```
import { FileTransfer } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';

providers: [
   ...
   FileTransfer,
   ...
]
```

Here is the error

> Type 'FileTransferOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
>     Type 'FileTransferOriginal' is missing the following properties from type 'FactoryProvider': provide, useFactoryts(2322)
>   (alias) const FileTransfer: FileTransferOriginal
>   import FileTransfer

Comment: which is the ionic-native/filetransfer version?

Comment: "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",

Comment: I was refering to the @ionic-native/file-transfer wrapper not the plugin version

Comment: Hello @SurajRao where can I see that wrapper version?

Comment: Are you using File component for read or write file ?

Comment: @CodeChanger, yes I have installed File: "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1"

Comment: I want to use FileTransfer to upload images to a server

Comment: you can see the version in package.json

Comment: "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.0.0"

Comment: ionic native 5.x seems to have issues in ionic v **3**  . eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54393555/ionic-3-plugin-backgroundmode-dont-work-object-is-not-a-function/54398504#54398504). Suggest installing 4.x stable

Answer (score 6):

You installed the latest `@ionic-native/file-transfer` (v5+).

Then you should import `FileTransfer` from `@ionic-native/file-transfer/ngx`

```
import { FileTransfer } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer/ngx';
```

Or else install `@ionic-native/file-transfer` with v4+, then you can import `FileTransfer` from `@ionic-native/file-transfer`

```
import { FileTransfer } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
```