# Background mode is not working in ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native, ionic5

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at index.js:249
    at Module../node_modules/@ionic-native/background-mode/index.js (index.js:405)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../src/app/app.component.ts (main.js:865)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../src/main.ts (environment.ts:19)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:13)
```

in package.json

```
"@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.803.23",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^8.2.14",
    "@capacitor/android": "^1.5.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "1.5.1",
    "@ionic-native/background-mode": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/clipboard": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "5.0.0-beta.15",
    "@ionic-native/deeplinks": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.22.0-beta-1",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.22.0-beta-1",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.26.0",
```

Comment: What is the output of 'ionic info', 'node -v'  ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IONIC 3: Plugin BackgroundMode dont work: Object(…) is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54393555/ionic-3-plugin-backgroundmode-dont-work-object-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.0.4
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.25
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.25
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.25
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0


Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)

   cordova-res                          : not installed
   native-run (update available: 1.3.0) : 0.3.0

System:

 
   NodeJS            : v10.19.0 (/usr/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.13.4

Comment: [console.log]: "background mode check" {
[ng]   "error": "plugin_not_installed"
[ng] } {
[ng]   "error": "plugin_not_installed"
[ng] } null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Check your project type in ionic.config.json file.

If the type is "ionic-angular", then install 4.x.x version.

npm i -s @ionic-native/background-mode@4.20.0
If the type is "angular", then install 5.x.x-beta version

npm i -s @ionic-native/background-mode@5.0.0-beta.24
```

Credit goes to - **Diego Desenvolvedor** for this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54393555/ionic-3-plugin-backgroundmode-dont-work-object-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-background-mode
npm install @ionic-native/background-mode
```

[Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode)