# Ionic Device Orientation getCurrentHeading returns an error

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, device-orientation

I tried using the [Ionic Device Orientation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device-orientation/) in an ionic project in order to find the heading direction of the device like the blue thing you have in Google Maps to show which direction you're heading to on a map. My final objective is to make a compass integrated in an ionic app.

Here is my function.

```
  public test() {
      this.deviceOrientation.getCurrentHeading().then(
          (data: DeviceOrientationCompassHeading) => console.log(data),
          (error: any) => console.log(error)
      );
  }
```

However when I try to run it I get the following error
[image]

My angular version is 5.2.11

My Ionic version is 4.18.0

If you have any idea where this might come from or if you have a suggestion on how to integrate a compass in an Ionic app feel free to share, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have installed device-orientation plugin (Version >= 5.0.0) which is supported for ionic 4. Since you are using ionic 3 uninstall the plugin and install 4.20.0 version.

```
npm uninstall @ionic-native/device-orientation
```

and then

```
npm i -s @ionic-native/device-orientation@4.20.0
```

If you have added 'ngx' at the end of your import, then remove it. It's for Angular 6. Since you are using Angular 5, It's not needed.

```
import { DeviceOrientation } from '@ionic-native/device-orientation';
```

For more detailed explanation, you can check out this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54398403/6617276

Hope this helps.